# Why does ArcGIS Server 10.1 change path variable to g_ESRI_variable_1?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I've had a problem with my geoprocessing service finding the data it needs for execution. I found out what's causing this is ArcGIS's assignment of a new variable "g_ESRI_variable_1" in the new copy of the code that lives on the server. However when I try to edit the code back to its original state it says "Permission Denied". I have already given rw permissions to my publisher server on the file server hosting the data and registered the folders in Server Manager.

Here are the top few lines of my original script:

```
import os, regUtil, regQueries, urllib, sys
from arcpy import GetParameterAsText

outpath = GetParameterAsText(1)
root_path = r'\\SERVERNAME\\Data\tiger\TigerData'
```

And here are the top few lines of the copy in the arcgisserver folder automatically made upon creation of the geoprocessing package:

```
import os, arcpy
g_ESRI_variable_1 = os.path.join(arcpy.env.packageWorkspace,u'tigerdata')
# Esri end of added variables

# Esri start of added imports
import sys, os, arcpy
# Esri end of added imports

import os, regUtil, regQueries, urllib, sys
from arcpy import GetParameterAsText

outpath = GetParameterAsText(1)
root_path = g_ESRI_variable_1
```

It seems very weird that ArcGIS would go in and [change a variable automatically](https://community.esri.com/thread/119295). Why does this happen and how would I either prevent this from happening or edit the script back to the way I wrote it?

Comment: The simple answer, the one you aren't looking for it: because it has to and you can't prevent it from happening.

Comment: But further to my comment, it appears you do not have the datastore setup, thus it is copying the data. That is why its updating the path to your data: so it'll run against the copied data.

Comment: mucking around in the system folders is not recommended. There are a few bugs logged about this issue depending on the source data type. To edit the script open your editor with elevated privileges (run as admin) and you will be able to edit and save.